# Google map, remove control from controls array

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, push

I have a google map and
I´m using a hacky solution for infowindows not to show up under a div that overlays the google map if a special user-interaction is done.

i execute this code after user-interaction :

```
var controlDiv = document.createElement('div');
controlDiv.style.width = '220px';
controlDiv.style.height = '500px';
map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_TOP].push(controlDiv);
```

that works wonderfully, but if the user closes the overlay i want to remove the element i pushed into the array.

i tryed to splice it out, but i have no idea how to select it, or what it´s index is.

```
map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_TOP].splice("?", 1);
```

other possibility may be

```
delete map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_TOP]
```

but i just dont get the element removed
plesea help
thanks in advance

Answer (score 14, accepted):

map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_TOP] isn't a native array, it's a [**google.maps.MVCArray**](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?hl=en&csw=1#MVCArray)

When you add only this single custom control to the array you may simply  call:

```
map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_TOP].clear();
```

When there are more custom controls iterate over the controls to find the index of `controlDiv` and call

```
map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_TOP].removeAt(index);
```

**Another approach:** instead of adding/removing the control add the control once and toggle the `display` of `controlDiv`.

Comment: Thank you very much!  .clear() is the perfect solution for me :D

Answer (score 3):

I found that the `setAt()` and `removeAt()` methods do not work well for map controls. Google only uses `push()` and `clear()` methods in their code samples.

Also, the `display` property may result in controls on top of each other after hiding and re-showing them. I found that the `visibility` property works best. Below a custom control constructor with google map style and a method to show/hide the control.

```
function CustomControl(options) { // constructor
    "use strict";
    this.div = document.createElement('div');
    this.div.style.visibility = "visible";
    var controlUI = document.createElement('div'); // Set CSS for the control border
    controlUI.style.backgroundColor = '#fff';
    controlUI.style.backgroundClip = 'padding-box';
    controlUI.style.border = '1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15)';
    controlUI.style.borderRadius = '2px';
    controlUI.style.boxShadow = 'rgba(0,0,0,.3) 0px 1px 4px -1px';
    controlUI.style.cursor = 'pointer';
    controlUI.style.margin = '5px 5px 15px';
    controlUI.style.minWidth = '120px';
    controlUI.style.textAlign = 'left';
    controlUI.style.position = 'relative';
    if (options.title) {
        controlUI.title = options.title;
    }
    if (options.visibility) { // "visible" or "hidden"
        controlUI.style.visibility = options.visibility;
    }
    this.div.appendChild(controlUI);
    var controlText = document.createElement('div'); //Set CSS for the control interior
    controlText.style.color = 'rgb(25,25,25)';
    controlText.style.fontFamily = 'Roboto,Arial,sans-serif';
    controlText.style.fontSize = '11px';
    controlText.style.fontWeight = '500';
    controlText.style.padding = '1px 6px';
    if (options.text) {
        controlText.innerHTML = options.text;
    }
    controlUI.appendChild(controlText);
    if (options.index) {
        this.div.index = options.index;
    }
    if (options.handler) {
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(controlUI, 'click', options.handler);
    }
    if (options.position) {
        this.position = options.position;
    }
    if (options.sequence) {
        this.sequence = options.sequence;
    }
    this.setVisible = function(bolean) { // method
        var visibility;
        if (bolean) { //true
            visibility = "visible";
        } else {
            visibility = "hidden";
        }
        controlUI.style.visibility = visibility;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not an answer to the question that was asked. Also, removeAt() works fine. I just used it with my own control without issue. I think the fact that Google happens to only use push() and clear() in their code samples  isn't really any kind of endorsement for what one should use, they are probably just work well enough for the samples.